# Checking for a list using Rcpp fails

Tags: r, rcpp

Consider these examples using `Rcpp` to check various data types. Why does my check for `is_list` return `FALSE`?

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('bool is_list(SEXP data) {
  return Rf_isList(data) ? true : false;
}')

cppFunction('bool is_data_frame(SEXP x) {
    return Rf_inherits(x, "data.frame") ? true : false;
}')

cppFunction('bool is_integer(SEXP data) {
  return Rf_isInteger(data) ? true : false;
}')

is_data_frame(list(a = 1))
# [1] FALSE
is_data_frame(data.frame())
# [1] TRUE
is_integer(1)
# [1] FALSE
is_integer(1L)
# [1] TRUE

## However, this is unexpected
is_list(list(a = 1))
[1] FALSE
```

#### References

- [Rinternals.h isList](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/48536f1756a88830076023db9566fbb2c1dbb29b/src/include/Rinternals.h#L1189) definition
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665942/5977215) that I was working through

Comment: Interesting.  Nothing here is really Rcpp apart from using Rcpp to marshal the build via `cppFunction`.  The `Rf_*` functions are R's, as are the types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - yes I debated whether Rcpp was relevant - I may have come to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: As an aside `cppFunction('int what_is_it(SEXP data) { return(TYPEOF(data)); }') ;  what_is_it(list(a=1))` returns `19` which is `19    VECSXP  list (generic vector) ` which is how `isNewList()` is defined: `INLINE_FUN Rboolean isNewList(SEXP s) { return (s == R_NilValue || TYPEOF(s) == VECSXP); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Rf_isNewList` instead. (Apparently the representation of lists changed at some point.)

This works:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('bool is_list(SEXP data) {
    return Rf_isNewList(data) ? true : false;
}')

is_list(list(a = 1))
#> TRUE

is_list(1)
#> FALSE
```

I think it's more idiomatic to do the following instead:

```
cppFunction('bool is_list(SEXP data) {
    return (TYPEOF(data) == VECSXP);
}')
```

This has the side-benefit that NULL is not a list.

Comment: Thanks. In my example the `is_list()` will work on `pairlists`, rather than `lists`, which requires the `Rf_isNewList` as you point out

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: And yes we have `VECSXP` a lot in Rcpp's code but use neither of those two predicates.

Answer (score 2):

This may be R.  Consider these two plain C functions against the R API which replicate your result, but do not involve any Rcpp:

```
R> library(inline)
R> f <- cfunction(signature(s="SEXP"), body="SEXP b = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1)); INTEGER(b)[0] = Rf_isList(s); UNPROTECT(1); return b;")
R> f(list(a=1))
[1] 0
R> g <- cfunction(signature(s="SEXP"), body="SEXP b = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1)); INTEGER(b)[0] = Rf_inherits(s, \"data.frame\"); UNPROTECT(1); return b;")
R> g(data.frame(a=1))
[1] 1
R>
```

So in essence `Rf_isList()` seems to miss list types. There may be a good reason behind it but I would not be able to name it right now ...

And digging a little we see in `src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h`

```
INLINE_FUN Rboolean isList(SEXP s)
{
    return (s == R_NilValue || TYPEOF(s) == LISTSXP);
}
```

which makes it a little hard to see where this could go wrong.  But maybe you want to poke there...

Comment: This helps - it's lead me to `is_list(pairlist(a = 1))` == `TRUE`. It appears a `list` in R is a `VECSXP`, whereas a `pairlist` is a `LISTSXP`